# Implementing Apache TinkerPop over my JavaBeans

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm new to graph databases (although I've extensive experience with Semantic Web technologies) and I'd like to understand if what I've in mind makes sense.

I've my own data model, made of Java's JavaBean objects, the model is rather similar to a graph, with a Node interface (and a few subclasses), an Edge interface (and a few subclasses), methods to query the model (get Node instances with attribute = 'x', get all edges for a node, etc).

I'd like to wrap this model with one of those query languages out there (let's say Cypher or Gremlin), so to have something more standardised and so that I can avoid implementing my own query language and, most importantly, my own query engine.

One obvious way would be to use Neo4j or some TinkerPop implementation as a backend for my object model (or similarly, to convert/synch my objects to a graph for one of those frameworks). However, because the model is already graph-like, has good search methods and efficient storage components (to/from simple XML files), I'm also thinking that maybe I could adapt a query language to my model. TinkerPop seems designed to support that.

Does this make sense? Is TinkerPop the best (or a good) way to go? Is/are there documentation/tutorials about that?

Comment: Is using the Spring Framework an option for you? If so, you could consider [Spring Data Neo4j](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/). It might be too heavyweight for your use case though.

Comment: thanks @GaborSzarnyas, that seems an interesting option, although not exactly what I'm looking for (can be used to use neo4j as backend, using the data model defintions in Java, I'd like to use my own objects/components as backend behind Cypher or another query language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a comitter of SimpleGraph I had similar needs that led me to starting the 
[SimpleGraph](http://www.bitplan.com/index.php/SimpleGraph) open source project in the first place.

For conversion of Pojos to and from Tinkerpop there is the [ORM/OGM stack FERMA](https://github.com/Syncleus/Ferma).

The idea of SimpleGraph is to "graphenize" other information sources e.g. the tabular structures of Excel Tabels or SQL databases.

Since your own data structures are already in graph form obviously the mapping to and from tinkerpop is much simpler. The SimpleGraph approach in this case would be a simple back and force (link) between the node and edge structures of so that each tinkerpop node corresponds to one of your nodes and tinkerpop each corresponds to one of your edges. I have succesfully used this approach e.g. for a graphical representation of UML models by mapping XML structural elements to tinkerpop elements and graphical representation elements in a graph editor at the same time. So my answers would be:

- Does this make sense?  **Yes**
- Is TinkerPop the best (or a good) way to go? **Yes**
- Is/are there documentation/tutorials about that? **I'd neither say Yes and No this one**

I have not seen a specific tutorial for your use case. If you experiment a bit e.g. with the SimpleGraph modules you might get a feeling how things work.

Comment: Many thanks, @Wolfang Fahl. SimpleGraph looks brilliant, I'll try it.